# Error on Angular 4 Service Constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I've create a service called MyDataService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class MyDataServiceService {

  constructor(private http:Http) {}//The Http parameter  shows an error

  getData(){
    this.http.get('http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerbiostats/?PerMode=Totals&Season=2016-17&LeagueID=00&SeasonType=Playoffs').subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(data)
    )
  }

}
```

On te constructor it shows  an error "Cannot find name Http" on the browser's console the error is "Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyDataServiceService: (?)."

this is app.componnet.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyDataServiceService } from './my-data-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

  constructor ( private service:MyDataServiceService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.service.getData();
  }
}
```

and  app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MyDataServiceService} from './my-data-service.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [MyDataServiceService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Do I missed something?

Comment: Well, you've not imported it. `import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';`. Note that Http is deprecated. Use HttpClient. https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to use http (new HttpClient) in your case:**

1. Import HttpClientModule in your module (Probably app.module.ts) if you didn't already
2. In your service, `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`
3. Change your `getData()` method to return the observable. the subscription should be in the component and not in your service:

   ```
   getData(){
       return this.http.get('http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerbiostats/?PerMode=Totals&Season=2016-17&LeagueID=00&SeasonType=Playoffs');
   }
   ```
4. Then in your component:

   ```
   ngOnInit(){
      this.service.getData().subscribe((data) => console.log(data));;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class MyDataServiceService {

  constructor(private http:Http) {}//The Http parameter  shows an error

  getData(){
    this.http.get('http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerbiostats/?PerMode=Totals&Season=2016-17&LeagueID=00&SeasonType=Playoffs').subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(data)
    )
  }

}
```